# Trouble applying Jquery effect on scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I will try to explain myself as clear as I can.

**What am I trying to do?**

I am trying to make the paragraph's opacity to be 1 when the scrollTop value is more than 40, and make the paragraph's opacity 0 again when the scrollTop value is less than 40. ( so basically when the user scroll down the text appears, when they scroll up again it disappears);

**What is my problem?**

I can make the text disappear when the scrollTop value is more than 40 by using the jQuery effect `fadeTo("slow", 1)`. However, I cannot make it disappear again when the value of scrollTop is less than 40.

Note: I set the opacity of the Paragraph to 0 by default.

Here is a link to my current code on codePen
http://codepen.io/kevin1616/pen/reLgQZ

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log(scrollPosition);
    if (scrollPosition > 40) {
        // apply effects and animations
        $('p').fadeTo("slow",1);
    } else if(scrollPosition < 40){
        // apply effects and animations
        $('p').fadeTo("slow",0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this can help you out!

```
if (scrollPosition > 40) {
    $('p').fadeIn("slow",1);
} else if(scrollPosition < 40){
    $('p').fadeOut("slow",0);
}
```

I'm sure that there is a better solution using toggle.

http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/